# Extract an attribute from a created point and set it as a project variable

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-modeler, qgis-variable

[image]
I am trying to create a QGIS modeler process by which the center point of the map on the desktop is used to query what County it falls in from a PostgreSQL data base and writes that county name as a string value to a project variable which can be used to fill in subsequent layout text boxes.

I have it all working except I can't seem to set the County_Var variable from the query.

See the attached image. Where I am wrong?

[image]

Comment: Extracted (Location) is expecting a path to the output layer destination

Comment: It's an expression.  You can't use the expression to take the value of an attribute and put it in a variable?  If you were exporting a layer file you would use the "Model Output" selection or "Value" instead of the "Pre-calculated Value" option.

Comment: My understanding of the algorithm is that the Extracted (location) parameter is the location of the output - either memory or a path to layer on disk. For instance you would use an expression in this context to construct a path from say the project folder variable.  Whatever is in that textbox has to be a layer destination.

Comment: OK.  Let's assume you are correct.  How can I peel an attribute out of that layer result and write that value to a Variable?  If there needs to be another step in the workflow, what is it?

Comment: I added another picture above if that helps. m

Comment: I'm not sure if it is possible, it probably needs some sort of workaround. I'll have a think about it but it will have to wait until tomorrow!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created such a model [you can download here](https://drive.switch.ch/index.php/s/jEP75NYguyBHKKH): enter a polygon layer for countries, enter a point layer and it creates a project variable with the name of the country the point lies within.

Here how to do it yourself:

1. The model consists of three parts (see screenshot): 1) a vector layer input, 2) Field calculator, 3) Set Project variable.

   [image]
2. In Field calculator, use `Pre-calculated Value` with this expression: `'overlay_within(''world'', NAME)[0]'`, where `world` is the name of the layer and `NAME` the attribute containing the country name you want to get. Be sure to have single quotes `'` and double single quotes `''` exactly like that!
3. In `Set project variable`, again use `Pre-calculated Value`, this time with this expression, where `@Field_calculator_OUTPUT` is the variable available in the expression string builder, based on the Field calculator algorithm and `country` the name of the field created there:

   ```
    attribute(
        get_feature_by_id(@Field_calculator_OUTPUT, 1),
        'country'
    )
   ```
4. In the `Set project variable` dialog window, go to Dependencies and check the box next to `Field calculator`.

When you now run the model, a project variable will be created with the name of the country the point from the input layer lies within:

[image]

Comment: Babel:  I had to make a couple mods as my spatial query is done from map center but the rest of it worked! Using field calculator was the ticket.  Well done and many thanks!